# Why is "the true data generating process" similar to simulating the entire universe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

In the deep learning book by Bengio, Goofellow and Courville (http://www.deeplearningbook.org/) there is paragraph in the regularization chapter.

"Deep learning algorithms are typically applied to extremely complicated domains such as images, audio sequences and text, for which the true generation process essentially involves simulating the entire universe."

Why is this the case?

Comment: for drug discovery in particular idk

Comment: How many pictures can possibly be taken? How many novels can possibly be written? How many noises can possibly be recorded?

Comment: the true data generating process is not going to yield every picture, or every sound though. The book advocates strongly for the manifold hypothesis and this seems to be in contradiction to that

Comment: You would be simulating every particle in the universe, so you'd have to store information about every particle in the universe in your computer. Even if you needed 1 bit of information for each particle, then still you would need some physical space for all the bits + extra memory for computation. This means that you'd need more physical space then there is particles in the universe ;) Further more, such "model" would be uninterpretable because of complexity -- and if you consider it interpretable why not interpret the universe directly?

Comment: @Abe How do you know the DGP doesn't yield every object? What if I'm trying to construct a model that can recognize a photo of any arbitrary object in any context taken from any angle from any distance? I would have to have a reference set of all objects that can and will exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is effectively the butterfly effect: any one tiny historical detail might have indirectly somehow changed, e.g., the exact text of *Oliver Twist*. So nearly everything that has happened is effectively part of the data-generating process.

While I think there is some merit to this argument, it applies just as well to traditional low-dimensional data like the approval ratings of US presidents, so I don't think it says anything special about high-dimensional data like images.